# Allow edit to be continued during imgur's image load

Tags: feature-request, images, editor, uploader, imgur

Can we have a functionality that will insert corresponding line immediately:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

and allow us to continue editing of a question or an answer while actual image will be loaded in the background? And only after this process is completed, this functionality will add another line:

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KWwr.png
```

"silently" in the end of text being edited without interrupting the work of the editor?

Recently (about 6 months into the past) *something has permanently gone really bad* and:

- at least for my location (southern Poland),
- even though I am on 600/60 Mbit cable connection,

uploading image as small as 5 kBytes takes approx. 5-10 seconds. Not mentioning really big images which upload to imgur can last 30+ seconds.

Currently image loader covers the whole editor and prevents edit from being continued. So each such upload means at least 15-30 seconds of break in editing the content. This is a very counter-productive as far as I know (correct me if I am wrong).

**EDIT (6 July 2020)**: *My main ISP upgraded my line and subscription plan to up to 900/90 Mbps and I was also playing around with quite a few other ISP providers and testing this in various geographical locations and... **nothing has changed for past 9 months**.*

*Uploading even a tiny image takes at least 10 seconds and editing is totally blocked during that. If I have a question or answer that includes three or more images then uploading all of them will most likely take more time in total than actually writing an post (I tend to keep things short).*

**We urgently need a feature of uploading images in background without blocking an editor in the same time**.

*Please, do not post answers and comments like "hmm... works for me" or "I upload images with a snap of fingers". I don't discuss internet speed here. I discuss **the lack of feature of background images upload** in the entire SE*.

Comment: I've been wondering about this for a while. It makes repairing third party image hosts a pain to do efficiently.

Comment: Try speedtest.net - I can't find a site in Poland but I can find one in the neighboring country: "Mobile TeleSystems JLLC
Minsk" that works at the expected speed. Searching through some Forums the common factors seemed to be the browser / computer configuration. Ask a friend nearby how it is for them.

Comment: My experience is that this speed does not depend very much much on the location. California, Germany, Vietnam and India have all a very comparable (and really annoyingly long) wait time. (Only China is different, behind the Great Firewall it does not make much sense to use imgur, so you also do not have to wait. ;-)

Comment: @Rob Can speedtest.net test my communication directly between my computer and SE / imgur? I doubt this. I am using this service on daily basis and it shows me something around half of network operator promised values -- i.e. around 300/30. When I copy files between my computer and my remote backup, I am getting a true speeds (in itself slow FTP protocol) of 8-12 MB/s (not MBps!), so it is certainly an issue in imgur or somewhere between me and imgur.

Comment: In the event that it's none of those three things your course of action is to contact imgur to ask *why* it's so slow. --- As far as implementation goes it's technically possible, and links can be numbered *live* and updated in correct order as you add new links during the upload. Should the background upload fail that would need to be detected, a means to signal SE (and you) be agreed upon, and the link deleted from underfoot (exactly *how* the nature of the error is to be explained remains to be determined). The UI for uploading was recently updated, another change may not be soon.

Comment: @Ollie I could write it down on a piece of paper or stop editing at all. That's not a point. I don't want to use "3rd party solution", because main editor forces me to wait 10 seconds during each image upload.

Comment: An update: most of the slowness wasn't coming from upload speed, but because Imgur's image processing was slow. This [has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353674/imgur-image-processing-takes-too-long), and it only now takes 1-2 seconds after clicking the upload button to image insertion. I still think this should be implemented, though, for users with slow upload speeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

This is now possible with the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) (currently an alpha test).  Look below:

[image]