# Focus stolen after image paste completed resulting in mistyping and retries

Tags: bug, images, uploader

Here's the scenario:

1. Start editing in the Markdown editor (question or answer text).
2. Paste an image from
   your clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
3. The image starts uploading - and can take a while.
4. While waiting, start editing the title of the question (maybe this would occur with other text also).
5. While you're typing, the image upload completes.
6. Focus immediately returns to the text of the embedded image.
7. *Your next keystroke wipes out the image.*
8. Do-over.

This doesn't seem intentional, or necessary?  I suppose if the change in focus for some reason can't be prevented, at least is there some other workaround?

This occurs consistently. I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: @JohnOmielan undo doesn't completely reverse it... it undoes the extra keystroke after the image uploaded, but doesn't restore the image itself.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Have you tried undoing twice, then?

Comment: I have tried it twice in succession, and no that hasn't worked for me, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs I suggest you add about you having tried to use the Undo operation multiple times to your question text as it's an important detail showing you are not able to undo what just happened.

Comment: Related: [Allow edit to be continued during imgur's image load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336046/289905).

Comment: Does it happen while it loads the pasted image, or uploads it to imgur itself?

Answer (score 2):

For me the focus isn't on the entire image itself:

[image: Screenshot of the browser focus after uploading an image]

It is on the "enter image description here" part only.
So continuing to type after the image upload results in typing an image description, which is a very much likeable result, as images do need more image descriptions.

This also occurs when on the ask page, and entering a title.

I am using Firefox on Mac.